# jquery hover div and show another div then keep that div open

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd really appreciate if someone can help me.

i just want to hover a div and show another div then i want to hover that div but that div still open

Code snippet:

```js
$(function(){
 $('.navigation li').hover(
   function(){
     $('.navigation-dropdown').toggleClass('visible');
    }
    );
});
```

```css
.navigation{
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
.navigation li{
  display: inline-block;
}
.navigation-dropdown{
  background-color:red;
  display: none;
}
.visible{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <a href=""><li>home</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>about</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>contact</li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="navigation-dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="" alt=""></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7okx2Lrx/7/

Comment: for demo use `<>` to include the code in OP

Comment: Just replace `toggleClass` with `addClass`

Comment: @Mazz actually i want to make that red div close again when mouse out that red div. can u help me to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need make some changes in the code. 
One of the variant would be:

```
$(function(){
  $('.navigation li').hover(
    function(){
      $('.navigation-dropdown').addClass('visible');
    }
  );
  $('.navigation-dropdown').hover(function(){}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('visible');
  }) 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7okx2Lrx/11/

Comment: hey, how to make the dropdown disappear without have to move the mouse to dropdown first?

Comment: The simples way is -  https://jsfiddle.net/7okx2Lrx/12/. You can play with time and if statement. Its just basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

Change below code

```
$('.navigation-dropdown').toggleClass('visible');
```

to

```
$('.navigation-dropdown').addClass('visible');
```

Answer (score 0):

The hover work only when the mouse is on the element.
Your should put your second element IN the first one, then when you will hover the second element, you will stay in the first one.

Working example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/7okx2Lrx/8/
I removed the height and the vertical margins:

```
.navigation ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `.toggleClass('visible')` to `.addClass('visible')`:

```js
$(function(){
 $('.navigation li').hover(
   function(){
     $('.navigation-dropdown').addClass('visible');
    }
    );
});
```

```css
.navigation{
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
.navigation li{
  display: inline-block;
}
.navigation-dropdown{
  background-color:red;
  display: none;
}
.visible{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <a href=""><li>home</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>about</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>contact</li></a>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="navigation-dropdown">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="" alt=""></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

I did it without javascript.

With the "+" you can select the next element on the same level.

```
.navigation:hover + .navigation-dropdown, .navigation-dropdown:hover{
    display: block;
}
```

And removed the margin from the ul

```
ul{margin: 0;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7okx2Lrx/10/